# xp:selectItem value property throws Conversion Error

Tags: xpages, radio-group

Within xp:RadioGroup there is xp:selectItem which requires itemLabel.
Data-Properties of xp:selectItem is either itemValue or value:
itemValue - is the value returned to the server
value - specifies the contest of the selection item (Can be literal string or expression)

Loading values in both value & itemValue throws an error e.g.

```
<xp:radioGroup  id="radioGroup" 
            layout="lineDirection" 
            dojoType="dijit/form/RadioButton" 
            styleClass="zmdi">

    <xp:selectItem  itemLabel='ssh' 
                itemValue="serverValue" 
                value="SelectionContentsValue">
    </xp:selectItem>

</xp:radioGroup>
```

The error thrown is:

Exception

```
Conversion Error setting value ''{0}'' for ''{1}''.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conversion Error setting value ''{0}'' for ''{1}''. 
com.sun.faces.util.Util.getSelectItems(Util.java:489)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.SelectManyCheckboxListRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectManyCheckboxListRenderer.java:130)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.RadioRenderer.encodeEnd(RadioRenderer.java:48)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeEnd(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:180)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:1005)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UISelectOneEx.encodeEnd(UISelectOneEx.java:331)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:858)
```

Removing the  [ value="SelectionContentsValue" ] attribute from the xp:selectItem  renders the radioGroup without issue.

ideas?  thx

Answer (score 1):

The **value** property of the  is intended to be evaluated to something that is a UISelectItem.

Here, you are assigning it to a String "SelectionContentsValue".

During rendering, the Renderer asks the radioGroup "Please give me your all your selectItems".

It does this by iterating through it's children, and checking if each child is a UISelectItem.

For each UISelectItem that it finds, it evaluates the **value** property.

- If value evaluates to null, it will then check for itemLabel, itemValue etc. and create the selectItem using these properties.
- else if value evaluates to a UISelectItem, it will use this UISelectItem
- else If value evaluates to something that is not a UISelectItem, it throws an IllegalArgumentException

Your situation is throwing the IllegalArgumentException because you have assigned a String to the 'value' property instead of a UISelectItem

So you should either use the itemLabel, itemValue properties and manually set those options that way. Or instead you can use the value property to compute the selectItem to one that has been prepared in some other place, or is dynamically loaded e.g. a managedBean or scoped variable.

I hope this helps let me know if any questions

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Cameron, you comment sparked an idea to go track down, which I found here:
[IBM Domino Designer> IBM Domino Designer 9.0.0> IBM Domino Designer User Guide> Designing XPages applications> Adding controls> Control reference selectItems - Selection Items](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_controls_cref_selectitems.html)

» Checkboxes can each checked "true", no mutual exclusivity with checkboxes.
Checkboxes are kinda like Hippies, "It's all cool man".
» Radio buttons are much more finicky:
 [image]

» Radios require itemLabel with itemValue aliase optional, for each selection option:

[image]

» The 'value' data-property is for checkboxes. Value contains pipe-delimited selection values, in an array/vector of checkbox choices.

```
<xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroup1" value="#{document1.fruit}">
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value>
                <![CDATA[${javascript:["Apples|apples|Garden of Eden|false","Oranges|oranges"]}]]>
        </xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
</xp:checkBoxGroup>
```

[image]